# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, set, typeerror

I"m getting this error as I try to make a ttk.Combobox using the values of a set that I select from a .db file.

```
for row in self.sql.execute("SELECT {0} FROM Songinfo".format(self.variable1.get())):
        self.List2.append(row)
        self.seen.add(row)
self.Option2 = ttk.Combobox(self, values=sorted(self.seen), textvariable=self.variable2)
self.Option2.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

`self.seen`, when printed out returns something like:

```
{('Heavy Metal',), ('Soundtrack',), ('Pop/Rock',), ('Metal',), 
 ('Alternative',), ('Alternative & Punk',), ('Rock',),
 ('Pop',), ('Classical Crossover',), (None,)}
```

this is a set of genres.  I'm getting that error and I'm not sure why, it wasn't an issue till recently, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should either remove the `None` tuple or nor add it to the list in the first place.

Comment: @DyZ I know this would fix it, but I've tried to .remove it but I haven't been successful

Comment: And how exactly did you try to remove it?

Comment: well, doing something like [x for x in self.newlist if x is not None].

Comment: `x` is set item. In your case, it is always a tuple and never a `None`, but its first element sometime is.  Try `{x for x in self.seen if x[0] is not None}`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you

Comment: Will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the offending tuple from your set:

```
self.seen = {x for x in self.seen if x[0] is not None}
```

Comment: By adding square brackets, you're introducing a failure case for the empty tuple.  Although it's conventional to test for None with is/is not, it's legal to test for it with ==, so it's safer to do {x for x in self.seen if x[0] != (None,)}

Comment: @AaronBentley While in general, you are right, in this case, all tuples are non-empty.

Comment: For what it's worth, this convention is pretty strongly worded in the PEP 8 standard, along with some good reasons not to use equality operators in cases like this. https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 5):

sorted(self.seen) is going to use < by default.  You can supply a cmp or key function if you don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was inserting a DataFrame and one of the column name was set to null.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).